# active scaffold: how can I set the confirm text on a delete action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activescaffold

So, I'm using activescaffold and have the following code:

```
config.actions = [:create, :delete, :list]
config.delete.link.confirm "Are you sure you want to delete this tag?"
```

which according to what I've googled should make the delete link confirmation box display that custom text... but it doesn't. It still uses some default question text. How can I customize the confirmation text?

Comment: are you doing a link_to or a button_to? and what version of rails, js lib, etc? how are you chaining these methods together?

Comment: active scaffold generates the link

Comment: Do you mean the Gem [ActiveScaffold](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold)? It is only mentioned as tag ...

Comment: The piece of code you are looking for is in `gems\railties-3.1.1\lib\rails\generators\erb\scaffold\templates\index.html.erb` and looks like `<%%= link_to 'Destroy', <%= singular_table_name %>, <%= key_value :confirm, "'Are you sure?'" %>, <%= key_value :method, ":delete" %> %>`. So it is not customisable.

Comment: @mliebelt activescaffold uses the plain rails scaffold code???

Answer (score 1):

It should work!

I have started a git rep to share code with fixes related to activescaffold.

You can see my controller here:
https://github.com/whizcreed/activescaffold-answers-to-stackoverflow/blob/master/app/controllers/notes_controller.rb

And here is the code that works correctly:

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  active_scaffold :notes  do  |config|
    config.columns = [:title, :content]
    config.delete.link.confirm = "Shows that you can change the confirm text  for delete!"
  end
end
```

I am using rails 2.3.10
and activescaffold branch: https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/tree/rails-2.3

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the `=`
it should be:

```
config.delete.link.confirm = "Are you sure you want to delete this tag?"
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not approach this problem using the view layer?

```
<%= button_to "Delete Foo", { :action => "delete", :id => @foo.id },
      :confirm => "For Real?!", :method => :delete %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html

Comment: that's all nice for vanilla rails, but this is with active scaffold